# Access List With Site To Site VPN

Tags: vpn, access-control, site-to-site

I have two juniper firewalls, an SSG-320M (screenos) and an SRX 340 (junos).  I'm required to connect to a third party with an IPSEC VPN, however I'd like some additional protection from my firewall.

I'd like to apply an access list to an IPSEC tunnel.  I've used a policy based and route based VPN.  In each case I'm asked to specify the services but this appears to have no effect.  I'm not sure if I need to bind a tunnel interface into a separate zone or if I should be using another feature altogether.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a route based VPN, but I bound my tunnel interface to the trust zone rather than the untrust zone so my access lists didn't work.  It's amazing what happens when you follow the instructions